# Karate Scenario Outline with expression in the Example

Tags: karate

I have a feature that uses Scenario Outline and want some of the fields to use the current date. I’ve got a today() function that does this:

Something like this:

```
   Examples:
     | date       | amount |
     | 2011-01-12 | 100 |
     | today()    | 200 |
```

is something like this possible, or are the expressions only available when defining the table?

The docs have an example  https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/dynamic-generator.feature  for defining the examples by expression,

```
   Examples:
     | karate.setup().data |
```

but this looks to be creating the entire table rather than running a function in the table